# Accessing Database and write into Beans | Best Practices

Tags: java, jdbc, javabeans

I have some payments which must be loaded into a `TableView`. To do this, I wrote two classes.

This one creates a connection to the Database and gets this information from a `.properties` file

```
package jdbc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
/**
 * JDBCAccess bietet Zugriff auf eine Datenbank.
 * Hierzu werden die Zugangsdaten aus einer Properties Datei geladen welche sich im im Ordner
 * 'db' befinden.
 * @author Christian
 *
 */
public final class JDBCAccess {

    private Connection connection;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String dbURL;
    private String driverURL;

    private static final String dbPropsPath = "db/db-props.properties";

    /**
     * Standar Konstrukter der Klasse.
     * Beim Aufruf dieses Konstruktors wird die connectTo Methode automatisch mit aufgerufen
     */
    public JDBCAccess() {
        super();
    }

     /**
      * Lädt die Parameter aus der Properties Datei direkt in die Variabeln
      */
    private void loadParameters() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Properties dbProps = new Properties();
        File dbPropsFile = new File(dbPropsPath);
        dbProps.load(new FileInputStream(dbPropsFile));
        username = dbProps.getProperty("username");
        password = dbProps.getProperty("password");
        dbURL = dbProps.getProperty("dbURL");
        driverURL = dbProps.getProperty("driverURL");
    }

    /**
     * Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen
     * 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException db-props.properties Datei konnte nicht gefunden werden
     * @throws IOException db-props.properties Datei, laden fehlgeschlagen
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException Fehler in Treiber URL
     * @throws SQLException Verbindungsaufbau zur Datenbank fehlgeschlagen
     */
    public void connectTo() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        if (connection == null || connection.isClosed()) {
            loadParameters();
            Class.forName(driverURL);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Schließt die Datenbankverbindung
     * 
     * @throws SQLException Schließen der Datenbank fehlgeschlagen
     */
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        if (connection != null && !connection.isClosed()) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

}
```

This one loads and saves the bean inside the database:

```
package beans;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import jdbc.JDBCAccess;

public class PaymentBean {

    private SimpleIntegerProperty id; //ID
    private SimpleDoubleProperty payment; //Betrag
    private SimpleStringProperty category; //Kategories
    private SimpleStringProperty usage; //Verwendungszweck
    private SimpleStringProperty date; //Datum

    private static Connection connection;

    private static final String EARNINGS_SQL = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENT WHERE PAYMENT >= 0;";
    private static final String SPENDING_SQL = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENT WHERE PAYMENT < 0;";
    private static final String ALL_SQL = "SELECT * FROM PAYMENT;";

    /**
     * Standarkonstruktor, initialisiert alle privaten Felder, sodass sie
     * benutzt werden können
     */
    public PaymentBean() {
        super();
        id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        payment = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        category = new SimpleStringProperty();
        usage = new SimpleStringProperty();
        date = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }


    public final int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public final void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public final double getPayment() {
        return payment.get();
    }

    public final void setPayment(double payment) {
        this.payment.set(payment);
    }

    public final String getCategory() {
        return category.get();
    }

    public final void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category.set(category);
    }

    public final String getUsage() {
        return usage.get();
    }

    public final void setUsage(String usage) {
        this.usage.set(usage);
    }

    public final String getDate() {
        return date.get();
    }

    public final void setDate(String date) {
        this.date.set(date);
    }


    /******************************
     * DATENBANK ZUGRIFFEDER BEAN *
     *****************************/

    /**
     * Diese Methode wird von allen Methoden benutzt, die Daten aus
     * der Datenbank in ein ResultSet laden. Dieses ResultSet wird in eine
     * ObservableList<PaymentBean> geladen, um somit ein Abbild in einer Tabelle zu erstellen
     * @param connection Datenbankverbindung, muss schon geöffnet sein
     * @param sql SQL Befehl, welcherv ausgeführt werden soll
     * @return Liste mit Datenbankergebnissen
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    private static ObservableList<PaymentBean> loadFromDB(final JDBCAccess jdbc, String sql) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        jdbc.connectTo();
        connection = jdbc.getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            ObservableList<PaymentBean> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                PaymentBean pb = new PaymentBean();
                pb.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                pb.setPayment(rs.getDouble(2));
                pb.setDate(rs.getString(3));
                pb.setUsage(rs.getString(4));
                pb.setCategory(rs.getString(5));
                data.add(pb);
            }

            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
            jdbc.close();
            return data;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Statische Methode um alle PaymentBeans aus der angegebenen Datenbank zu laden
     * @param connection Verbindung zur Datenbank
     * @return Gibt alle Zahlungen in Form einer ObservableList<PaymentBean> zurück 
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static ObservableList<PaymentBean> loadBeansFromDB(JDBCAccess jdbc) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        return loadFromDB(jdbc, ALL_SQL);
    }

    /**
     * Statische Methode um alle Einzahlungen aus der angegebenen Datenbank zu laden
     * @param connection Datenbankverbindung
     * @return Gibt alle Einzahlungen in Form einer ObservableList<PaymentBean> zurück 
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static ObservableList<PaymentBean> loadEarningsFromDB(JDBCAccess jdbc) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        return loadFromDB(jdbc, EARNINGS_SQL);
    }

    /**
     * Statische Methode um alle Auszahlungen aus der angegebenen Datenbank zu laden 
     * @param connection Datenbankverbindung
     * @return Gibt alle Auszahlungen in Form einer ObservableList<PaymentBean> zurück
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static ObservableList<PaymentBean> loadSpendingsFromDB(JDBCAccess jdbc) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        return loadFromDB(jdbc, SPENDING_SQL);
    }

    public static double getTotalSum(JDBCAccess jdbc) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        jdbc.connectTo();
        connection = jdbc.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT SUM(PAYMENT) FROM PAYMENT;";
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        rs.next();
        jdbc.close();
        return rs.getDouble(1);
    }

    /**
     * Speichert die Bean in der Datenbank ab
     * @param connection Datanbankverbindung
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public void saveInDB(JDBCAccess jdbc) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        jdbc.connectTo();
        connection = jdbc.getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            String sql = "INSERT INTO PAYMENT (PAYMENT,DATE,USAGE,CATEGORY) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
            PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            insert.setDouble(1, payment.get());
            insert.setString(2, date.get());
            insert.setString(3, usage.get());
            insert.setString(4, category.get());
            insert.executeUpdate();
            insert.close();
            jdbc.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updatet die Bean in der Datenbank
     * @param connection Verbindung zur Datenbank
     * @param id ID der zu updatenden Bean
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public void updateBeanInDB(JDBCAccess jdbc, int id) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        jdbc.connectTo();
        connection = jdbc.getConnection();
        if (connection != null) {
            String sql = "UPDATE PAYMENT "
                    + "SET PAYMENT = ? ,DATE = ? ,USAGE=? ,CATEGORY=?  "
                    + "WHERE ID = ?;";
            PreparedStatement insert = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            insert.setDouble(1, payment.get());
            insert.setString(2, date.get());
            insert.setString(3, usage.get());
            insert.setString(4, category.get());
            insert.setInt(5, id);
            insert.executeUpdate();
            insert.close();
            jdbc.close();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Löscht die Bean aus der Datenbank
     * @param connection Verbindung zur Datenbank
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public void delete(JDBCAccess jdbc) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        jdbc.connectTo();
        connection = jdbc.getConnection();
        String sql = "DELETE FROM PAYMENT WHERE ID = ?;";
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, this.id.get());
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.close();
        jdbc.close();
    }

}
```

With the `SimpleXXXProperty`, the properties could be represented without any code in the `TableView`.

What can I do better? Is it ok that I write to the database from a payment bean method, or should I access the database from outside of this bean?

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do better?

Why not use an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like hibernate.

> Is it ok that I write to the database from a payment bean method, or
>   should I access the database from outside of this bean?

The database access you are doing is not contained completely inside the bean. A client will need to pass a JDBCAccess object to do any db task - so not very convenient. Its just combining the model & dao into 1 class.

Also to consider if this bean is part of a distribution API or only used in your app as a persistence model. If its API, then you are distributing the internals of your persistence logic to clients and also forcing a dependency on the JDBCAccess class.

**Comments on code**: Consider not throwing checked exceptions. Do operations like `connection.close()` in finally.

Comment: Thanks for yours answer. Know I look for some stuff about hibernate.